# Is it wrong to have two animations on one element?

Tags: javascript, anime.js

I've got a function that looks like this:

```js
function(logMessage, logMessageIndex) {
    window.anime({
        targets: logMessage.get(0),        
        duration: 500,
            ...
    });
    window.anime({
        targets: logMessage.get(0),
        duration: 500,
        delay: 500 + (200 * logMessageIndex),
        ...
    });
}
```

I know this could be done in a timeline, but it's not. This appears to work the way I want, but my question is, is it *wrong*? Should I always use a timeline if I want to animate the same element more than once?

Comment: I don't think it's wrong, it just seems outdated ([timeline released in 2017](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/releases/tag/v2.0.0))